# Find difference of same column names across different data frames in a list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of data frames with same column names where each dataframe corresponds to a month

```
June_2018 <- data.frame(Features=c("abc","def","ghi","jkl"), Metric1=c(100,200,250,450), Metric2=c(1000,2000,5000,6000))
July_2018 <- data.frame(Features=c("abc","def","ghi","jkl"), Metric1=c(140,250,125,400), Metric2=c(2000,3000,2000,3000))
Aug_2018 <- data.frame(Features=c("abc","def","ghi","jkl"), Metric1=c(200,150,250,600), Metric2=c(1500,2000,4000,2000))
Sep_2018 <- data.frame(Features=c("abc","def","ghi","jkl"), Metric1=c(500,500,1000,100), Metric2=c(500,4000,6000,8000))
lst1 <- list(Aug_2018,June_2018,July_2018,Sep_2018)
names(lst1) <- c("Aug_2018","June_2018","July_2018","Sep_2018")
```

I intend to create a new column in each of the data frames in the list named Percent_Change_Metric1 and Percent_Change_Metric2 by doing below calculation

```
for (i in names(lst1)){
lst1[[i]]$Percent_Change_Metric1 <- ((lst1[[i+1]]$Metric1-lst1[[i]]$Metric1)*100/lst1[[i]]$Metric1)
lst1[[i]]$Percent_Change_Metric2 <- ((lst1[[i+1]]$Metric2-lst1[[i]]$Metric2)*100/lst1[[i]]$Metric2)
```

}

However, obviously the i in for loop is against  the names(lst1) and wouldn't work

Also, the dataframes in my list in random order and not ordered by month-year. So the calculation to subtract successive dataframes' columns isn't entirely accurate.

Please advise

1. How I go about with adding the Percent_change_Metric1 and
   Percent_change_Metric2
2. How to choose the dataframe corresponding
   to next month to arrive at the correct Percent_Change

   Thanks for the guidance

Comment: You are looping through `names` and then use `i+1`.  Instead it can be `for(i in seq_along(lst1))`  Also, as it is incrementing it is better to have the index to not have the last index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with `base R`

```
lst1[-length(lst1)] <- Map(function(x, y) 
     transform(y, Percent_Change_Metric1 = (x$Metric1 - Metric1) * 100/Metric1, 
     Percent_Change_Metric2 = (x$Metric2 - Metric2) * 100/Metric2),
          lst1[-1], lst1[-length(lst1)])
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @akrun. Your solution would work perfectly had my list been ordered by dataframes in Ascending order of Month-Years. However, the dataframes in my list are in a random order. Is there any way I can order my dataframes in the list by their month-year (captured in names) before I apply the transformation advised by you. Thanks a lot again

Comment: @Vish Yes, sure.  You can.  `library(zoo);lst2 <- lst1[order(as.yearmon(names(lst1)))]`

Comment: The above reordering mechanism worked after I replaced "-" with a space character. Thanks a lot

Comment: In case where a month has an extra row in feature which is missing in previous month, how do I skip the new row and apply the transformation suggested by you to only the rows that are present in Both the months?

Comment: @Vish Not clear about the question.  Can you post it as a new question

Comment: sure . will do. Thank you